# How to generate COM-Poisson distributed random numbers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, poisson, data-generation

I am performing a simulation study in MATLAB. I have to generate random numbers from the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson distribution. I know how to do it in R by using the existing packages, but I want to do it manually in MATLAB since all my simulation codes are written in MATLAB.

The following formula describes the PMF of distribution. It is from Guikema & Goffelt (2008)

```
P(Y=y)=(1/S(mu,nu))(mu^y/y!)^nu
```

where,

```
S(mu,nu)=sum^inf_0(mu^n/n!)^nu
```